# How do I have a php file write inside an included file?

Tags: php

If a php file is included/required, that has a `fwrite` function inside that included/required it, then no files will be written!

The only way to write would be to access the included/required file directly so an activity of writing to `log.txt` can begin.

Is there any way around this?

**main.php**

```
require("inside.php")
```

**inside.php**

```
//debug mode
$myFile = "test.txt"; $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, "testing shiz"."\n"); fwrite($fh, "============="."\n");
fclose($fh);
```

When main.php is run, the file will not write. Only when inside.php is run, does it write.

Comment: So you want to write a file which you want to include? This is some kind of dirty why don't you use eval? It's bad too but who cares in this case.

Comment: i'm confused by your question :/ are you writing to another file from the included PHP file? Or are you trying to write to the PHP file that is already included?

Comment: The included file is the one that is writing, yes.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: that's just wrong fwrite() will work in an include() or require() file

Comment: @dagon - yeah, I would guess it's a path thing but hard to say without seeing what he's really up to.

Comment: I don't really need the problem solved, I was just curious. ;) I'll post a code sample soon.

Comment: can't imagine why some one would think a particular core function would not work inside and included file.

Comment: I've added a code sample now.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the included/required file is not in the same directory as the file that calls it? That means it doesn't end up where you think it will.

For example:

*www.domain.com/file.php* has the following:

```
include('directory/write_file.php');
```

If *write_file.php* has a `fwrite`-statement in it, say to `'log.txt'`, the file will be placed in your root folder: *www.domain.com/log.txt*, because *file.php* is in your root folder and that is your current working directory (if needed, use [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) to fetch the current working directory).

To make sure the file is put in the right place, use an absolute path, for example:

```
/var/www/httpdocs/logs/log.txt
```

Again, you can use the `getcwd()`-function to find out what directory it has to be.